# trying to implement tail function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

as a part of learning Haskell, i'm trying to implement my own version of various functions related to list, here my impleentation of tail function so far

```
tail' :: [a] -> [a]
tail' [a] = []
tail' (_:y:xs) = y:tail' xs
```

i'm learning haskell

Answer (score 2):

Your `tail'` recurses and will leave out the first, third, fifth, etc. elements. Indeed:

```
   tail' [1,4,2,5]
-> 4 : tail' [2,5]
-> 4 : 5 : tail' []
```

tail does not need any recursion (nor tail recursion :) ), you can just unpack the "cons" of the list, and return the tail, so:

```
tail' :: [a] -> [a]
tail' (_:xs) = xs
```

for the empty list, there is no result, making `tail'` a *non-total* function, which is often not a good idea in Haskell. Often a `Maybe` is used to simulate non-total function, where we return `Nothing` in case there is no result, so:

```
tail' :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
tail' [] = Nothing
tail' (_:xs) = Just xs
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253670/discussion-on-answer-by-willem-van-onsem-trying-to-implement-tail-function-in-ha); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.